# TFilestream write gives unexpected results

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE2 and Win10 running in a Parallels VM. I create the file like this:

```
logfile := TFilestream.Create(WRITE_PATH + 'Log.txt', fmCreate);
```

This is the write:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Logit(const sToLog: string);
var
len: cardinal;
ss, sx: UTF8String;
str: string;
begin
if mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].checked then
begin
    str := 'Line #: ' + intToStr(GridLine) + #13#10;
    ss := UTF8String(str);
    len := length(ss);
    logfile.WriteBuffer(ss[1],len);
    ss := '';    
    str := '';
    len := 0;
    sx := UTF8String(sToLog);
    len := length(sx);
    logfile.WriteBuffer(sx[1], len);
  end;
end;
```

And the result. Note the extra 'Line #: -3' on the 'Sending' lines. I'd like to get rid of that. The 'Returned' line is produced in another proc. Hours spent searching for the answer revealed no solution, or even another example. Maybe I searched on the wrong words.

```
Line #: -3
Sending MN050;Line #: -3
Sending DS;Line #: -3
Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584
```

changed code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Logit(sToLog: string);
var
  len: cardinal;
  ss, sx: UTF8String;
  str: string;
begin
  str := mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].Caption;
  if mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].checked then
  begin
    if flag then
    begin
      str := 'Line #: ' + intToStr(GridLine) + #13#10;
      ss := UTF8String(str);
      len := length(ss);
      logfile.WriteBuffer(ss[1],len);
    end;
    flag := false;
    ss := UTF8String('');
    sx := UTF8String(sToLog) + #13#10;
    len := length(sx);
    logfile.WriteBuffer(sx[1], len);
  end;
end;
```

The result:

```
Line #: -3
Sending MN050;
Sending DS;
Sending DS;Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 183.1767

Line #: -4
Sending MN072;DS;
Returned DS@@@@@ON@ in 175.8367

Line #: -5
Sending MN026;
Sending DS;
Returned DS@@@03539 in 175.4539
```

Comment: Can you show a [MCVE]. This code is also very unwieldy. You really need to abstract yourself to a higher level. You should have a class that you can send strings to and have them logged. Instead you seem to have an unholy mix of UI code and file handling code.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you tell me why my code fails the minimal, complete, verifiable criteria? And while I agree a class would be an improvement, I don't know how that alone would solve my problem.

Comment: On a side note, you should consider using `TStreamWriter` instead of `TFileStream` directly.  `TStreamWriter` can wrap a `TFileStream` (even create one internally), and has `WriteLine()` methods that accept standard `String` values as input and can write them as UTF-8 in its output.

Comment: Looks like you called: `Logit('Sending MN050;'); Logit('Sending DS;'); Logit('Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584');` (Which you don't mention.) This logged what you see in in 3 stages as: `Line #: -3<CRLF>Sending MN050;` _then_ `Line #: -3<CRLF>Sending DS;` _then_ `Line #: -3<CRLF>Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584` ... All that's happening is you're seeing the 1st line from 2nd call on the same line as 1st call; and similarly: 1st line from 3rd call on same line as 2nd call.

Comment: PS: You could have trivially figured this out by stepping through the code in the debugger, and checking your log file at each stage.

Comment: @Mike Follow my link to understand that

Comment: @Craig - Thanks. Actually, I did mention it. 'The 'Returned' line is produced in another proc.". Your assessment of the cause is correct. I must have stepped thru that code 50 times and didn't see it. Couldn't look at the file while it's open.

Comment: @Mike Aah yes, you need to ensure the file is opened in a way that permits sharing. If I remember correctly, the Delphi wrappers are a bit of a nuisance in this regard. I think I resorted to creating a file, closing it, then opening with shared write access.

Comment: @craig THandleStream and CreateFile do the job well

Answer (score 4):

It sems you misinterpret the content of the log and how it is written.
The first call to the procedure results in

```
Line #: -3<CRLF>
Sending MN050;
```

(I added the `<CRLF>` to indicate the new line characters)

Note, no `<CRLF>` after the second line.
Therefore the next call is concatenated to the second line of the first call

```
Line #: -3<CRLF>
Sending MN050;Line #: -3<CRLF>
Sending DS;
```

The third call again concatenates to the end of the previous

```
Line #: -3<CRLF>
Sending MN050;Line #: -3<CRLF>
Sending DS;Line #: -3<CRLF>
Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584
```

Maybe your intention was to have something like this:

```
Line #: -3 Sending MN050;<CRLF>
Line #: -3 Sending DS;<CRLF>
Line #: -3 Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584<CRLF>
```

That you can achieve by moving the `+ #13#10`
from

```
str := 'Line #: ' + intToStr(GridLine) + #13#10;
```

to

```
sx := UTF8String(sToLog + #13#10);
```

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. The idea was to remove all the 'Line #' occurrences in a group except the initial one. See edited code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't add `#13#10` CRLF sequence after `sToLog` string, so next `Line #:` goes to the same line.
Possible correction

```
str := sToLog + #13#10;
len := 0;
sx := UTF8String(str);
```

but you'd better to rewrite this code to standalone function or method with GridLine and sToLog parameters

Comment: Thanks. Adding a CRLF there gives me

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you are not writing a line break after the second line, so the first line of a future log message gets appended to the second line of a previous log message.  So you need to add a line break to the second line that is being written.

I would suggest changing your code to use `TStreamWriter` instead of `TFileStream` directly.

```
logfile := TStreamWriter.Create(WRITE_PATH + 'Log.txt', False, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

If you want the log to look like this:

> Line #: -3
>   Sending MN050;
>   Line #: -3
>   Sending DS;
>   Line #: -3
>   Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584

Then you can do this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Logit(const sToLog: string);
begin
  if mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].Checked then
  begin
    logfile.WriteLine('Line #: ' + IntToStr(GridLine));
    logfile.WriteLine(sToLog);
  end;
end;
```

If you want the log to look like this instead:

> Line #: -3 Sending MN050;
>   Line #: -3 Sending DS;
>   Line #: -3 Returned DSANT=ATV@ in 168.5584

Then you can do this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Logit(const sToLog: string);
begin
  if mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].Checked then
  begin
    logfile.Write('Line #: ' + IntToStr(GridLine) + ' ');
    logfile.WriteLine(sToLog);
  end;
end;
```

Or simply this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Logit(const sToLog: string);
begin
  if mnuMain.Items[1].Items[2].Checked then
    logfile.WriteLine('Line #: %d %s', [GridLine, sToLog]);
end;
```